Argo Workflows Ingress - Facing 503 Error
I have been trying to deploy argo workflows and access the UI via an ingress. however, I have tried every possible configuration at this point and still getting a 503 error:
I deployed the helm chart onto my GKE cluster along with nginx ingress. Below is my current ingress configuration for my argo workflows values file.
Argo Workflows Ingress Configs
When i deploy it, it points to my backend service for argo workflows which is named "argo-workflows-server" - I am able to port-forward to this so the service and pod behind it is definitley working.
I've tried every possible configuration for the ingress annotations, along with the path and port name etc, but just can't figure it out. it seems a lot of people faced the same issue but i couldn't find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated
See above see above se

Please don't include images of code particularly when it's straightforward to copy-paste the code directly into the question. Images may not outlive questions and their content is less accessible to those trying to repro your issue.

It's salient that you can kubectl port-forwarrd to the service but your question doesn't include evidence (show commands and output) that (a) the NGINX Ingress Controller is installed and working correctly; (b) the Ingress you're creating exists (the image doesn't include a metadata.name which is concerning) perhaps kubectl describe ingress/${name} --namespace=${namespace}; (c) the Google Cloud resources that should results from the NGINX Ingress Controller programming a load-balancer

For the latter gcloud compute forwarding-rules list --project=${PROJECT} --format=yaml and gcloud compute target-pools list --project=${PROJECT} --format=yaml would be useful. I'm not familiar with using NGINX Ingress (instead of Google's own) and unsure how|whether the platform correlates Google Cloud forwarding-rules and target-pools to Kubernetes Ingress(es).
